# How to use Filter property of SPOSitePropertiesEnumerableFilter class

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, pnp, office-dev-pnp

I would like to know how "Filter" property can be use. This is a string value but I do not see any example anywhere on how to use this property.

I would really appreciate if someone can share some working examples here. Also would like to see what all types of filters I can do with "Filter" property.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt779490%28v%3doffice.15%29

Answer (score 0):

The "**Filter**" property of **SPOSitePropertiesEnumerableFilter** specifies the script block of the server-side filter to apply. The type must be a valid filter name and value must be in the form {$_PropertyName "filterValue"}. Valid operators are as follows: **eq, ne, like, notlike**.

Example: The property pass **"Url -like 'sales'"**, will returns all sites including 'sales' in the url.

Check the example code below.

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Commands/Admin/GetTenantSite.cs

Comment: The link you shared is for PowerShell command. Is it true for CSOM as well?